# Silverlight 4 - Explicit style clearing properties from implicit one (especially template)

Tags: silverlight, templates, styles

If I create a class that inherits from `ContentControl` and create an implicit style which sets the `Template` property to something (doesn't matter what), then I create an explicit style which also sets one of the properties, let's say `Background`, why is it the case that when I instantiate the element in XAML with the explicit style set my `Template` gets overridden.

So.. If I create a class as such: 
`public class MyContentControl : ContentControl`

create an implicit style with the template set to something (let's just say I wrap the `ContentPresenter` in a `Border`).

create an explicit style "MyStyle" with `<Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />`

Then instantiate:
`<my:MyContentControl Style={StaticResource MyStyle} />`

I look at my control after its OnApplyTemplate has been called, and the `Template` property reflects the template for `ContentControl` rather than my template. If I take out the explicit style, it works fine.

This is confusing to me because the very same works with the `Button` class. I can create a `Button` style that does not set `Template`. I suppose it might have something to do with `ButtonBase` not having a template, but I'm not sure what is causing this behavior.

I am aware that I can simply `StaticReference` my template in my explicit styles, but I'm still curious as to what is causing this behavior, so please don't submit answers tell me to do that instead. This question is purely for my understanding.